# Android SelectAll functionality for Recycleview {unable to acomplish}

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have `ReçycleView` with multiple photos in grid view, and i want to accomplish **Select All** functionality,

when there are less items in grid that can be view on the screen without scroll, i can do the select all functionality without any problem as this all ***views are bind to the recycle view***.

But the problem occurs when the items are more and are in scrollview and the items that are off screen ***i.e they are still not bind to the `RecycleView`*** and this time when the user press the select all, only the images that are viewed and **Bind** to Viewholder are getting selected.

I have gone through many trial and error but failed to do the same.
Request you to come-up with some solution.

Below is the RecycleView ImageItem Model and the data i need for the selection.

```
ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem(path, imageView, layoutImage, 
albumImage, selectionImage, uploadProgress, false, file, dbAlbumPhotos);


 case SELECT_ALL:
 if (imageHashMap != null && imageHashMap.size() > 0) {
    for (ImageItem imageItem : imageHashMap.values()) {
        if (!imageItem.isSelected()) {
            imageItem.setSelected(true);
            imageItem.getSelectionImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectedImageUrls.put(imageItem.getDbAlbumPhoto().getPhotoId(), imageItem.getDbAlbumPhoto().getUrlPhotoLarge());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is selectedImageUrls?

Comment: those are the urls of the images nothing else

Answer (score 1):

**Problem** with your code is that you are updating only those items view which are currently visible.
Whenever the user chooses for functinolaity Select All, just iterate and update all the `ImageItem` or java bean or model values to true.
Call `YourRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()` that the dataset has changed. Now if user unselect or select any single item then update only that bean object and call `YourRecyclerView.notifyItemChanged(int pos)` that item at position has changed.

**Update 1**: Don't put `layoutImage` in `ImageItem` bean. You need not put any `ViewHolder` in `ImageItem`. Now `holder.layout image` value can be set based upon `if(imageItem.isSelected()) holder.layout image.setVisibilit(View.Visible) else //View.Invisible`. `holder.layout image` will be always available in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: you are correct i can iterate all objects and do the same. But, the problem is how am i going to get the layout ** layoutImage**, that is view holder.layout image?

Comment: Are you storing  holder.layout image in bean class?

Comment: i am putting the values for ImageItems object in the BindVeiwHolder

Comment: and this the issues when the items that are not on the screen, the are not bonded to the recycleview till then  and when i selectall the displayed images are only getting selected

Comment: do you mean, i should set the ui based on the isSelected

Comment: Exactly you are very correct. I hope now you understand based on the answer I updated.

Comment: Would you agree to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136147/discussion-between-anurag-singh-and-raut-darpan).